# Mouse hook - freezing program

Tags: delphi, hook

I downloaded a mouse hook sample, which didn't work. So I stripped all the unnecessary stuff and would like to know what is wrong in it. When I start the program, both it and Delphi freeze and I have to close it through taskmgr.

App:

```
type
...
    procedure ms(var message: tmessage); message WM_USER+1234;

  end;

var
  MainHookTestForm: TMainHookTestForm;

implementation
procedure HookMouse; stdcall; external 'MouseHook.DLL'; // Added stdcalls;
procedure UnHookMouse; stdcall; external 'MouseHook.DLL';

{$R *.dfm}    

procedure TMainHookTestForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HookMouse;
end;

procedure TMainHookTestForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnHookMouse;
end;

procedure TMainHookTestForm.ms(var message: tmessage);
begin
  Label1.Caption:=format('%d - %d',[message.LParam, message.WParam]); // Edited
end;
```

Lib:

```
library MouseHook;
uses
  Forms,
  Windows,
  Messages;

var Hook: HHOOK;
{$R *.res}

function HookProc(nCode: Integer; MsgID: WParam; Data: LParam): LResult; stdcall;
var
  mousePoint: TPoint;
begin
  mousePoint := PMouseHookStruct(Data)^.pt;
  PostMessage(FindWindow('TMainHookTestForm', 'Main'), WM_USER+1234, mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y); // Edited class name
  Result := CallNextHookEx(Hook,nCode,MsgID,Data);
end;

procedure HookMouse; stdcall;
begin
  if Hook = 0 then Hook:=SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,@HookProc,HInstance,0);
end;

procedure UnHookMouse; stdcall;
begin
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook);
  Hook:=0;
end;

exports
  HookMouse, UnHookMouse;

begin
end.
```

I think this is as simple as it gets. The freeze happens at the call of `HookMouse`, when this line is executed, the whole IDE freezes and I can't debug further. But I can't see anything wrong in that procedure.

I am using XE2, if that helps. Thanks for the troubleshooting

---

***Edit***: I edited the calls of `HookMouse` and `UnhookMouse` with `stdcall;` and the name of the window class to find. It seems to be working nice now, it shows correct values, BUT only if the mouse cursor is not in the app window - when I move the mouse to the window, it changes to the `HourGlass` and the Label caption stops updating. What could cause this?

Comment: Try running the sample as Administrator - I remember that my VB6 windows hook apps got wonky in Windows 7.

Comment: I am running an admin account, but even rightclicking the exe and running admin didn't help

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but since you declared `HookMouse` with the `stdcall` directive, try including it when importing the function from DLL, i.e. `procedure HookMouse; stdcall; external 'MouseHook.DLL';`

Comment: I recommend using a low level mouse hook. The big advantage is that your dll doesn't get injected into all other applications, in fact you don't even need a dll in the first place.

Comment: I thought that when I don't use DLL I won't get the mouse messages when my form is not active...? I need to use mouse processing for other applications

Comment: Dear downvoter, can you provide further reasons behind your decision? I tried to get the question as clear as possible and if you are missing something, just commend and I will add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code

1.You are missing the `stdcall` calling convention:

```
procedure HookMouse; stdcall; external 'MouseHook.DLL';
procedure UnHookMouse; stdcall; external 'MouseHook.DLL';
```

2.You are changing the caption in the main form. so `FindWindow` (in the DLL) will find the window only once. you can use TMemo to debug:

```
procedure TMainHookTestForm.ms(var message: tmessage);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(format('%d - %d',[message.LParam, message.WParam]));
end;
```

2.1.The class name `MainHookTestForm` is not correct. should be:

```
FindWindow('TMainHookTestForm', 'Main')
```

Note the **T** MainHookTestForm

3.in the `HookProc` you must use:

```
if nCode = HC_ACTION then
begin
  mousePoint := PMouseHookStruct(Data)^.pt;      
  PostMessage(FindWindow('TMainHookTestForm', 'Main'), WM_USER+1234, mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y);
end;  

Result := CallNextHookEx(Hook,nCode,MsgID,Data);
```

Comment: I played a bit with the code, so I changed some things. I will update the question accordingly. I will try the 3) though

Comment: at least comment your code where you changed it, **after** I posted the answer. your class name is still not correct in the DLL FindWodow: should be: **T**MainHookTestForm

Comment: Sorry and please have look at the Edit part on the very bottom of my answer.

Comment: Everything is working just fine for me. Try to use `WH_MOUSE_LL` (14) instead of `WH_MOUSE`.